# How to loop through returned JSON data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am currently creating a JSON form in a custom Joomla component that makes a call to a function to grab an array of postcodes then returns this to the view. I then want to loop through all the returned postcodes in order to display them. 
I can't seem to get the jQuery.each loop to loop through the returned values correctly. Here is my code:

view:

```
jQuery.each(data.postcode, function() {
        html += "<span class='btn posctodeInv'>" + v + "</span>";                       
    });
```

controller:

```
$club_id = $_POST['club_id'];
$model = $this->getModel('postcodes');
$postcodes = $model->getClubPostcodes($club_id);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($postcodes);
```

model:

```
public function getClubPostcodes($club_id) {
        $query = "SELECT postcode FROM #__postcodes_to_club WHERE club_id = '" . (int)$club_id . "'";
        $this->_db->setQuery($query);
        $result = $this->_db->loadAssocList();

        return $result;
    }
```

and the returned json shown in Firebug console:

```
[{"postcode":"cr4"},{"postcode":"cr5"},{"postcode":"cr6"}]
```

Can anyone shed any light as to why my loop is throwing up an error?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery.each(data, function(index, val) {
    html += "<span class='btn posctodeInv'>" + val.postcode + "</span>";                       
});
```

Comment: Brilliant this worked. Thanks! Been on holiday for two weeks so don't think my brain is quite working correctly yet!

Answer (score 2):

Try, need index and val parameter to loop in jQuery.each

```
jQuery.each(data, function(index, val) {
        html += "<span class='btn posctodeInv'>" + val.postcode + "</span>";                       
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonp = '[{"Lang":"jQuery","ID":"1"},{"Lang":"C#","ID":"2"}]';
  var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonp);
  $.each(obj, function() {
      alert( this['Lang']);
  });
```

I think your problem is similar as above. Try above method